# What is wrong in the following javascript/nodejs code?

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
module.exports=function(config)
{
  var SphereClient = require('sphere-node-sdk').SphereClient;
  var Config = require(config.config_dir+'/sphereio');
  var client = new SphereClient(Config);
  var ret=
  {
    get:function(module){return require('./'+module)(client);}
  };
  return ret;
}
```

It says error after get:function( : Unexpected '('. Is there some invalid syntax? I even tried changing get to geet or someting else, still the error occures.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get
May be char ":" says to parser that "get" is a key, not a getter? Delete ":", what happends?

Comment: The code works for me. No syntax error here.

Comment: I suspect the error with require('./'+module)(client) code. what module file containes?

Comment: But... why getter has an arguments?? `get:function()` not `get:function(foo)`.

Comment: Hello all, there was an error in the file "module" which had triggered the error. BTW, this is not a getter but merely a key.  @venkat7668 . Thanks there was problem in the module getting required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These types of error may occur if there is a syntax error (or the js compiler says there is a syntax error) in the file getting required. The compiler gives no hint of the line in the target file.